# How to display Filenames in gridview on the basis of date selected from two calendar controls (DateFrom to Dte to) in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, gridview

How to display Filenames in Gridview on the basis of date selected from two calendar controls (DateFrom to DateTo) in asp.net c#. I have Gridview control and Two calendar controls. when user will select Dates in calendar control  i want to display stored files in the Gridview between selected months range.

Comment: This question cannot be answered as originally posted as the details are objectively ambiguous

Answer (score -2):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;


namespace WindowsFormsApplication24
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        const string FOLDER = @"c:\temp";
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            dateTimePickerStart.Value = DateTime.Parse("1/1/2017");
            dateTimePickerEnd.Value = DateTime.Now;


            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(FOLDER).Where(x => (File.GetLastWriteTime(x) >= dateTimePickerStart.Value) && (File.GetLastWriteTime(x) <= dateTimePickerEnd.Value)).ToArray();



        }

    }

}
```